# cant import the .so file on jupyter

Tags: python, pybind11

i am working on an ubuntu server, i installed jupyterhub and i am trying to import some modules binded whit pybind11, the directori looks like

```
- base:
   - cpp_core:
         - backtester.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

   - dashboard:
         - dash.ipynb
```

then in the first cell of the jupyter notebook i use

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../cpp_core')
from cpp_core import backtester
```

and then i get this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'backtester' from 'cpp_core' (unknown location)
```

i will be grated whit any help, if i need to add more info ill be on the look to update

Comment: Your import looks for a package or module "cpp_core" **in** directory "cpp_core". This is one "cpp_core" too much.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i just tried just import backtester and import cpp_core.backtester should i need to remove the sys.path.append?

Comment: Your directory structure shows "cpp" while your code says "cpp_core".

Comment: my bad both should be cpp_core, i edit the question

Comment: Does it work if you don't use jupyter?

Comment: solved! it was my python version, i have 3.8 and the bind was made whit 3.9