# pybind11 module cannot be found in Jupyter, but can be found in command line python and Spyder

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, pybind11, modulenotfounderror

Folks, I am having this puzzle with a pybind11 library mytest.cp37-win_amd64.pyd put in C:\Temp.
Then I have this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Temp")
from mytest import *
```

Now here comes the problem, if I launch the python in command line:

```
>python
>>>import sys
>>>sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Temp")
>>>from mytest import *
```

It works fine. Or I just put above code in test.py, then run:

```
>python test.py
```

It also works. If I put this piece of code in Spyder, it works as well. But if I put this piece of code in Jupyter, it will not work by saying:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mytest'

I am sure all my tests are conducted in the same python environment by printing it out:

```
import os
print(os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'])
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: The file `mytest` would need to have a copy be at the same location of the notebook or in the current working directory of the notebook? Or use the magic command `%cd` to change to the location of `mytest` while in the notebook. What is seen when you type `pwd` in a cell in the notebook before and after trying `%cd` to change the working directory?

Comment: The notebook is launched in a different directory. But I have sys.insert(0, r"C:\Temp") before trying to import mytest. Does it work differently in Jupyter?

Comment: You should test using `pwd` (or check what the path is from inside the notebooks) as I suggested because I get `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'insert'` trying your command `sys.insert(0, r"C:\Temp").

Comment: My bad, it's a typo, should be sys.path.insert(~). I have corrected my question. The issue is still there.

Comment: With `sys.path.insert()` it works (see result via `print(sys.path)`) to add that to the PATH. So the import seems like it should work without needing the another copy. (Because it works with a test in my Jupyter session, although I had the added to PATH a directory below the current working drive in my test.) Did you try and see the difference now with `print(sys.path)` **inside** your notebook and it still won't import `mytest`?

Comment: Wayne, I was using sys.path.insert() from the beginning, and it does not work in Jupyter. The same code works in Spyder and command line.
I also made sure the python virtual environment is the same across the usage.
I wonder there is anything required to be configured for Jupyter to get pybind11 going.

Comment: `sys.path.insert()` does work from inside the Jupyter notebook. I described how tested it on a linux session after adding a sub-directory and importing `mytest` script that was in there. I just don't know if Jupyter respects it when it is on the level in the hierarchy you have it. That is why I'm asking you to just copy your stuff into the current working drive or below. If below, add that to the path. Or remove pyBind and just try to import a Python script from the location you are trying from.

Comment: Have you looked into suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71446739/cant-import-the-so-file-on-jupyter)? Or tried following [the example here that uses Jupyter I think](https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663-2018/notebooks/S13C_pybind11.html) to  compare how it is done there or try something different than your code?

Comment: Wayne, thank you for the advices. It seems my Jupyter does not recognize pybind11 library. I put the library in the local folder where I launch the notebook, it still fails, while it recognizes a python script in the same location.
This is weird since both Spyder and command line would recognize the pybind11 library in the same Conda environment.

Comment: I found the problem related to the link you provided. The python version of my Jupyter is different from the version I used to build my pybind11 library even though the Jupyter is sitting in the same virtual conda environment. I will summarize my finding in a formal answer, thank you Wayne!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Wayne's help and [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71446739/cant-import-the-so-file-on-jupyter), I finally found out the root cause, that is the version of the python running in the Jupyter kernel is different from that of the environment from which the Jupyter is launch and also the pybind11 library is build with.
After I reinstall the Jupyter in the environment again, the library is picked up successfully.